# Can I use laravel validation rules inside the custom validation class?

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I want to check the input is an email inside the validation class.I use custom validation for that because of the email comes as a list separated by commas.I want to get email one by one and validate them.
Can I check whether email is valid without using regex?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$emailsInput = Input::get('email');
$emails = explode(',', $emails);
foreach($emails as $email) {
    $validator = Validator::make(
        ['email' => $email],
        ['email' => 'required|email']
    );
    if ($validator->fails())
    {
     // There is an invalid email in the input.
    }
}
```

Assuming that the input's format is like:
test1@gmail.com,test2@gmail.com,etc@gmail.com